# I am trying to create a way to mergeSort with generics. Why does Java keep saying that I am converting my generic type E[] into an integer?

Tags: generics, mergesort, type-parameter

Java is showing the error on lines 11, and 13. Incompatible types: E[] cannot be converted to int.

```
package holdClasses;

public class sortMethods<E> {
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void mergeSort(E[]list){
        if (list.length > 1){
            E[] firstHalf = (E[]) new Object[list.length / 2];
            System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length /2);
            mergeSort(firstHalf);
            
            E[] secondHalfLength = (E[]) new Object[list.length - list.length / 2];
            E[] secondHalf = new [secondHalfLength];
            System.arraycopy(list, list.length / 2,
                    secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
            mergeSort(secondHalf);
        }
    }
```

I tried converting it to an Object because you cannot create a generic array in java but converting it to the Object created this new problem where it says its being converted into an integer.

Comment: `E[] secondHalf = new [secondHalfLength];` ?

Comment: And if the class only has static methods you don't want the type parameter on the class.

Comment: @tgdavies E[] secondHalf = new [secondHalfLength]; is what is causing the error. Okay I can change it to no longer be static. I need to sort an int, double, and string so it has to be generic right?

Comment: What do you think that syntax does? Presumably you mean `E[] secondHalf = new Object[secondHalfLength];` Look at the type of `secondHalfLength` and where you are using it.

Comment: @tgdavies I tried that as well and it gives the exact same problem.

Comment: What type is `secondHalfLength`? What are you using it for?

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you. Asking me that simple question just made me realize how ridiculous what I was trying to do was and I fixed it.

Comment: No problem, Incidentally, you don't need to make your function non-static. You can have a static, generic function in a non-generic class.